# Need help in manipulation of Excel 2007 table

Tags: excel

Here are some statistics about my question(related to excel 2007)....

- some thousands lines of data from web (so highly unstructured)....
- Each row acting as a tuple ..(each row has data related to a particular entity with various attributes)
- there are about 60-100 attributes for each row... i.e. some row has 60 attributes(followed by corresponding attribute value in next cell of same row) while some has 100 attributes(values)
- These attributes are not structured and not in any particular pattern..(i.e. in some row Attribute "Music" is at column "A" and its associated value is at column "B" but in other row ,Attribute "Music" is at column "AB" and its value is at "AC"....

So here is my question
Is there any tool/excel utility which can group all attributes of same name under a particular column and its associated value in the next column  .[IMP: the row order must not be changed as these attributes are associated row wise with some primary key]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very broad question but I can give some suggestions. I don't know of any tool/utility to do what you need. However here are three options that you could use to get the result you want.

1. Figure out how to import into a database based on attribute name/value. Not sure this is possible without structuring the data first (organize each attribute into its own column).
2. Use formulas HLOOKUP/VLOOKUP/INDEX/MATCH to organize each attribute into its own column. No VBA with this option but uses very complex formulas.
3. Use VBA to loop through the rows and organize each attribute into its own column. This might be the easiest to implement logically but that depends on your skills.

Usually we want to see what you've tried before we help. You can explore each of these ideas on your own then post additional questions for specific problems you encounter. Show us your own effort as much as you can. We like to help correct specific code problems rather than simply create your program for you.

---

EDIT

Here are the formulas for method 2: The data is in Sheet1 and the formulas are in Sheet2.
[image: Spreadsheet]

Here is the formula in Sheet2!A2; copy down as far as needed.

> =Sheet1!A2

Here is the formula in Sheet2!B2; copy down and across as far as needed.

> =IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B$1,Sheet1!$A2:$K2,0)),"",INDEX(Sheet1!$A2:$K2,1,MATCH(B$1,Sheet1!$A2:$K2,0)+1))

Best wishes.

Comment: The problem again remains the same....To import to any database, the file should have same format(not valid in this case)   i can try point no. 2 but as i am relatively new to excel programming so i need elaboration of point no. 2 means how to use these commands...??

Comment: Use MATCH to find the column number of the data then use INDEX to return the data.

Comment: Thanks for the help..... The formula seems to be returning result. I will again post final outcome once i am done with the sheet...